# Grappling Hook not grappling player in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

i'm trying to program a grappling hook in C# in Unity.
The idea is to throw a ball gameobject to an gameobject with the tag "Hookable" and bring the player where the ball grabbed.
The ball can be thrown and recognizes collision successfully but doesn't bring the player with it.
The code seems to be correct and the console doesn't give any warnings but, i don't understand what's happening for not working.
Here's the code, sorry if this sounds noobish:

The grappling hook (attached to player gameobject):

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrapplingHook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject hook;
    public GameObject hookHolder;

    public float hookTravelSpeed;
    public float playerTravelSpeed;

    public static  bool fired;
    public bool hooked;

    public float maxDistance;
    private float currentDistance;

    void Update()
    {
    //firing the hook
        if(/*Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)*/Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H) && fired == false)
            fired = true;

        if (fired == true && hooked == false)
        {
            hook.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * hookTravelSpeed);
            currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, hook.transform.position);

            if(currentDistance >= maxDistance)
                ReturnHook();
        }

        if(hooked == true)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
            hook.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * playerTravelSpeed);
            float distanceToHook = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, hook.transform.position);

            if(distanceToHook < 1)
                ReturnHook();
        }
    }

    void ReturnHook()
    {
        hook.transform.position = hookHolder.transform.position;
        fired = false;
        hooked = false;
    }

}
```

Here's the code that checks if the grappling hook is detected (attached to Hook and Hookable object):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HookDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
        if(other.tag == "Hookable")
        {
        player.GetComponent<GrapplingHook>().hooked = true;
        Debug.Log("Tocou");
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I had put the script attached to the wrong gameobject, the solution was to attach to the player GameObject.